# Does the order of GROUPBY and JOIN matter?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have two tables: one containing information about an animal and their weight measurements, and the other about specific breeds within that species.

Table A

| Kingdom | Class | Species | Weight (lbs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Animal | Mammal | Dog | 50 |
| Animal | Mammal | Dog | 30 |
| Animal | Mammal | Cat | 10 |
| Animal | Mammal | Cat | 5 |

Table B

| Species | Breed |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | Chihuahua |
| Dog | Golden Retriever |
| Dog | Jack Russell Terrier |
| Cat | Persian |
| Cat | Siamese |
| Cat | Calico |

I would like to display the average weight *per species* next to each *breed*. The table that I want is:

| Kingdom | Class | Species | Breed | Avg. Species Weight (lbs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Animal | Mammal | Dog | Chihuahua | 40 |
| Animal | Mammal | Dog | Golden Retriever | 40 |
| Animal | Mammal | Dog | Jack Russell Terrier | 40 |
| Animal | Mammal | Cat | Persian | 7.5 |
| Animal | Mammal | Cat | Siamese | 7.5 |
| Animal | Mammal | Cat | Calico | 7.5 |

I did this in two ways:

1. Join Table A and Table B on `Species`, and then calculate the average weight
2. Calculate the average weight in Table A, and then join with Table B on `Species`

Intuitively, I know that I will get the same result regardless if I do the join before or after the group by, *as long as I group by the equivalent columns*. In method 1, I need to `group by Kingdom, Class, Species, Breed`. In method 2, I need to `group by Kingdom, Class, Species` (since `Species` is the join key that gets broken down into `Breeds`, the resulting tables are equivalent.)

However, I suspect that method 1 is more optimal since the group by before the join aggregates the data and prevents it from exploding if we have many weight measurements. This should hypothetically facilitate the join.

I'm planning to refactor my code to replace all usage of method 2 with method 1. Before I do that, is there a mathematical proof that group by and join operations are commutative so I can generalize this optimization?

Comment: yes the order of the grou by matters, the join doesn't matter

Comment: Your many instances of animals with weights (table A) does not include a breed, so how can you average by breed?  First record in A is "dog".  Is that a chihuahua or a retriever?  Don't know, cannot categorize it.

Comment: Edited my question for better clarity -- basically, it doesn't matter that I don't have weight measurements per breed. I just want to display the average weight per species next to each breed.

Comment: When in doubt, GROUP BY in subqueries _before_ joining,

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the average value first and then join it with your second table -

```
SELECT a.Kingdom, a.Class, a.Species, b.Breed, "Avg. Species Weight (lbs)"
  FROM table_b b
  JOIN (SELECT Kingdom, Class, Species, AVG("Weight (lbs)") "Avg. Species Weight (lbs)"
          FROM table_a a
         GROUP BY Kingdom, Class, Species
       ) ON b.Species = a.Species
```